# Unity3D if condition with bool failing to send variable value to another script c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making my first game, and I am having trouble updating a bool value using a toggle button.

This is the button:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;
using Assets.Code.Scripts;
using Assets.Code.PowerPlants;

namespace Assets.Code.States

public void ShowIt()
{
    HydroElectric.t1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 55, 100, 50), HydroElectric.t1Bool, "Turbina 2 MW");
    GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 100, 60, 80, 25), HydroElectric.prod.ToString ()); // PRODUCED ENERGY 
}
```

This is where I have the if condition:

```
using System;

namespace Assets.Code.PowerPlants

public class HydroElectric
{
    public static bool t1Bool = true;
    public int turbina1;
    public static float prod = 0;

    public HydroElectric ()
    {
        if (t1Bool == true)
        {
            turbina1 = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            turbina1 =0;
        }

        prod = turbina1;
    } 
}
```

I have no errors on the console, the bool value is changing (I used debug) but the value of turbina1 is not changing (when I debug it from the first script). I have no idea why its value is not changing along with the true or false condition. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `HydroElectric` class the constructor takes the value of `t1Bool` at the time that the object is created and uses it to calculate the value of `prod`.  After that point there is nothing in your code that will change the value of `prod` when the value of `t1Bool` changes.

Instead of setting the value once you could have it calculate the `prod` from the value of `t1Bool` each time you read it:

```
public class HydroElectric
{
    public static bool t1Bool = true;
    public static float prod
    {
        get
        {
            return t1Bool ? 2f : 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can set the value of `prod` whenever the value of `t1Bool` changes:

```
public class HydroElectric
{
    private static bool _t1Bool = true;
    public static bool t1Bool 
    {
        get { return _t1Bool; }
        set
        {
            _t1Bool = value;
            prod = value ? 2f : 0f;
        }
    }

    public static float prod = 2f;
}
```

This is slightly faster, but only enough so to make a difference when you are checking the value of `prod` very frequently.

There are other ways to respond to changing state including event handlers and implicit notifier lists.  Just remember that if you want something to happen you have to *make* it happen, and that assigning a value type (simple things like numbers and booleans as well as complex `struct` types) won't keep updating them over time.

Comment: But you understand that I use a toggle button to manipulate the value of turbina 1 right? Your code is a bit advanced for me, I feel I have to study a bit to understand. Also I have also turbina 2 and turbina 3. All three are summed in prod.

Comment: Also, why you used float?

Comment: You only showed `turbina1` in your sample code, and didn't reference it outside the constructor so I ignored it.  If you need those values, add them. The code itself is fairly simple property get/set stuff which you should learn because it is _very_ common in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Your bool condition is executed in the constructor, which means that `HydroElectric.t1Bool` will not work because `turbina1` is already set when `HydroElectric` is instantiated. Put your bool condition in a separate method and call that from your script.